# React router BrowserHistory still asks for hash

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-router

I recently started learning react but I ran into an issue:
I am using laravel homestead for my server and on the front-end I am using react. I have to stop displaying the hash sign so in my router I switched from HashRouter to BrowserRouter like so:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
                    <div style={styles.content}>
                        <div className="content">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/login/:code/:state" component={Login}/>
                                <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
```

But when I try to access /login for example the app still asks for that hash: /#/login in order to access the component. Any ideas as to why is this happening? Thank you all for your time!

Comment: have you tried restarting the server and/or clearing the site's cache in your browser?

Comment: @user3229756 I have just done that, sadly with not result

Answer (score 0):

I have found my issue:
In my web.php routes I was redirecting the user to my welcome.blade only when the '/' route was accessed. All I had to do is change it to redirect it regardless of the route, like so:
How it looked before:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

After the change:

```
Route::get('{any}', function ($any) {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

So my issue had nothing to do with react it was regarding the laravel routing.